# How to insert a newline into TextField default?

Tags: pdf

I need to insert `\newline` character as part of `TextField` default.  The code below as suggested by Heiko Oberdiek in 2003 fails ([see "multiline TextField" site:tug.org:](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2003-April/003955.html))

```
\pdfstringdef\mytext{Hello\string\r World}

{
  \begin{Form}\TextField[multiline,name=toaddress,width=5cm,charsize=12pt,default=\mytext]{\mbox{}}
  \end{Form}
}
```

Any suggestions will be most welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to compile fine with `pdflatex` on my installation and creates a pdf with apparently some form field for text, as seems to be expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pdfstringdef\mytext{Hello\string\r World}

{
  \begin{Form}\TextField[multiline,name=toaddress,width=5cm,charsize=12pt,default=\mytext]{\mbox{}}
  \end{Form}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is a screen capture after having highlighted with the mouse the two words:
[image: hello world form]

Comment: maybe I should have said explicitely that I copied pasted the code given by Heiko Oberdiek in 2003 and just added to it the `\usepackage{hyperref}` which I think is the thing the OP was missing. I didn't have time to say all of that because I was rushing to get the `+100` bounty.

Comment: `\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}` caused the failure.

Comment: I didn't guess that!