# hyperref TextField displays wrong when xeLaTeX is used

Tags: xetex, pdftex, hyperref, textfield

I am trying hyperref textfield using [the minimum code posted here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120250/how-to-insert-a-newline-into-textfield-default).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pdfstringdef\mytext{Hello\string\r World}

{
  \begin{Form}\TextField[multiline,name=toaddress,width=5cm,charsize=12pt,default=\mytext]{\mbox{}}
  \end{Form}
}
\end{document}
```

The "Hello" is shown correctly when pdfLaTeX is used. However, if xeLaTeX is used, some non-recognizable stuff is generated, which can be shown by Chrome but not Adobe or MS Edge. Can you suggest whether and how to use xeLaTeX to display the content correctly ?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288553/hypertarget-with-accents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\pdfstringdef` here is wrong. As hyperref internally escapes the value you are now escaping it twice. Give the default value as simple text and enter the newline with `^^J`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
  \TextField[multiline,name=toaddress,width=5cm,charsize=12pt,default=Hello^^JWorld]{\mbox{}}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]